# difference between Sources and Resources

Tags: java

What are actual difference between Sources and Resources for a Java project? Which all types of files can come as sources and resources. Is there a specific criteria that I can follow

Comment: Source files are compiled and resources are not.

Answer (score 5):

resources contain all supporting files like properties, xml and other file which are used in java code.

and Source contain all java packages and classes.

you can read properties file using below code

```
InputStream addrStream = PropertyUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("<file-name>");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(addrStream);
```